# I want to travel to TRNC from India for my MBA program , do I need transit visa if I don't leave airport in turkey?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, turkey, student-visas, northern-cyprus

I want to travel to TRNC from India. I Have got admission for my MBA program at NEAR EAST UNIVERSITY. I applied for a transit visa for turkey but it was refused. I tried to know the reason but I did not get any response.
should I apply again for a transit visa? without knowing the reason for 1st refusal?
And I Checked Indians don't need visas to travel to TRNC.
I am booking my flight from Delhi to Ercan airport and 2hrs layout at Istanbul airport, CAN I TRAVEL WITHOUT HAVING TRANSIT VISA?

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. To answer we need to know your citizenship and whether you will have a single booking (one PNR) or if you are booking two separate flights

Comment: I AM INDIAN and I have not booked the fight yet I want to be sure before I book the flight

Comment: When are you planning to travel? According to Timatic, the system used by airlines, Passengers traveling to Ercan (ECN) arriving from India are not allowed to enter unless they have a TRNC passport or residence permit, or the passenger is a student. If you are eligible to enter, TWOV in Istanbul is possible with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours, providing you remain in the international transit area of the airport. https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external.php?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b

Comment: I have got admission to north Cyrus for the MBA program, I applied for a transit visa for turkey but they did not give me the visa. I am really confused should I apply again or I can travel to TRNC. College can provide me OK TO BOARD ticket. plz i really need help

Comment: Please edit your question to include **all** the relevant details of your situation. What reason was given for the transit visa refusal? Which college has offered you admission and for how long? Do you have the relevant TRNC entry visa (study, presumably)?

Comment: No reason for visa refusal, for indian TRNC is visa free or visa on arrival. 2years MBA PROGRAM at NEAR EAST UNVERSITY

Comment: Have you obtained your student residence permit from the university? https://aday.neu.edu.tr/student-permit-procedure-online-immigration/?lang=en

Comment: No I have to do it once I reach there and apply for a student residence permit